# making the displayed image only clickable in an imagebutton

Tags: android, onclicklistener, imagebutton

I have an `ImageButton` in my `Activity` as follows:

```
 <ImageButton 
   android:contentDescription="@string/controller"
   android:id="@+id/control"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="3"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   android:src="@drawable/displayed_image" />
```

regarding to some **UI** standardization required I can't assign the image width to any thing but `match_parent`, So, the resulted image is like:

All I want to do make only the **displayed image** is the *clickable* part of the Image and whole of the **transparent-area** is not *clickable*,so that when assigning an `onClickListener` for the `ImageButton` the action executed only if the clicking was in the **displayed-image**, is there's any static or programmatic way to afford that?

[image]

Comment: What is the type of the container of your ImageButton? Is it a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout ...? Could you post all related xml?

Comment: @Plinio.Santos LinearLayout

Comment: And the handler method, how are you setting it?

Comment: @Plinio.Santos a regular `new OnClickListener()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not wrap the imageButton in a RelativeLayout, that has a match_parent width and then have the imagebutton set to wrap_content and centerInParent

Answer (score 1):

You could try using something like this: http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/ - But to be honest, there are other ways of doing it.

A couple of other ideas:

1. Have 3 separate images within the container. A left and right piece and your clickable image piece. Combined they'd look exactly the same as the original single `ImageView`. The benefit is, that you'd be able to control the centre piece and ignore any other touches/clicks. This would probably require a `RelativeLayout`. I don't know if that goes against your UI concerns.
2. Overlay a different view (ImageButton possibly?), to handle the click for you. So in effect you'd end up with something like: [   []   ] (Where the brackets represent each view - the larger of the two being your original).

Hope this helps.

Comment: well, the link you provided me won't work with me due to standardization among all devices So that i can't handle any numbers way in my UI, the other two ways would be a good work-around but looks like the answer before you (specially the first one) and so I choose the first one as the correct answer regarding to the priority of oldest answer.

Comment: You don't have to justify your acceptance of answers :) Whatever works for you! Glad you got it sorted though!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the image button height and width to `wrap_content`. Then add the property `android:layout_gravity="center"`. Just it.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't stop the user clicking outside of the 'red' area, which is what OP is asking.

Comment: yea as @LokiSinclair said, that won't help

Comment: You're right. I have posted with `mach_parent` and this should be `wrap_content` though.